# Issue executing javascript code in phone but not in desktop maybe for video load

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video-streaming

i have a page showing a video when it loads and then when you click outside it hides the video and show the rest of pages content, it works fine on desktop but on phones it show all at the same time and doesn't seems like javascript is working. The code goes like:

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('#video1').hide();
    $('#rest').show();
```

});

and inside the body i have a inserted video from youtube which is the video showing at start.
You can find the page at www.infinitejourneyproject.com. Please help.

Comment: works for me... I don't see any issue here

Comment: did you visit the page with a phone?

Comment: yes, I used chrome on my android device

Comment: that's is weird, because I try it on my android device also with chrome and somebody else also do it on a iphone, but yesterday i kind of made some fix to it, I'd made a very stupid typo, like 'div[id^="project"' where should be 'div[id^="project"]' (note the square bracket at the end) on a jquery selector

Comment: I made the same typo error this past week... worked on all browsers but threw an error on iOS devices.